# jQuery Post Not Working in OS X Chrome

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome

I have the following code:

```
$.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: 'mylink.com/coupon2.php',
        crossDomain: true,
        data: '{"some":"json"}',
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function(responseData, textStatus, jqXHR) {
          //$( "#coupon_code" ).html("Coupon code: " + responseData.data.code);
            //var value = responseData;
          //var json = JSON.parse(responseData);
          $( "#coupon_code" ).html("Coupon code: " + responseData.data);
        },
        error: function (responseData, textStatus, errorThrown) {
            $( "#coupon_code" ).html( 'POST failed. ' + errorThrown + ', ' + responseData );
        }
    });
```

It works fine in Chrome and Firefox on Windows, but doesn't post or subsequently return in Chrome on OS X.  Why would this be?

Comment: Could you open your console and see if there is any output?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue was not browser or OS specific, it was strictly associated with attempting to make cross origin requests from a secure connection to an insecure connection.  When testing the code on the Windows PC, I wasn't connected to the initial site via https.  However, when I tested it on the Mac, I was connected to the initial site via https, and attempting to post to a non-https url.  This is why the post functioned on the PC, and subsequently failed on the Mac.